# How to render dynamic directives, functions and params in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have an object that I'm iterating over with ngRepeat. This object includes information on what kind of directives to render in the markup and also what values to give those directives. I haven't been able to do this type of dynamic rendering with Angular so far, it would really make the templates feel like reusable templates.

*Controller*

```
$scope.myFunk = function(obj) {
  alert(obj.target);
};

$scope.fruits = [
  {
    label: 'Banana',
    params: { target: 'ground' },
    action: {
      directive: 'ng-click',
      value: $scope.myFunk
    }
  }
];
```

*Template*

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">
    <!-- Expecting to see "ground" in an alert() when clicking -->
    <a href {{fruit.action.directive}}="{{fruit.action.value}}{{(fruit.params)}}">
      {{fruit.label}}
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[Here's a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AzmHmgNbSjPAQ7ZN3Bgy?p=preview)

I'm trying to get angular to evaluate something like this:

```
<li>
  <a href ng-click="myFunk({ target: 'ground' })">Banana</a>
</li>
```

Usually I'd simply declare directives in the markup the general angular-way, but here I really need to have the flexibility of rendering arbitrary directives with individual values that may be functions with their own parameters.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How "general" are we talking here. Are there a handful of patterns or just any generic code there?

Comment: @JohnMunsch The directives would be either ng-click, my-directive or similar. The function supplied to the directives would be predefined in the controller and always a part of the object subject to iteration, the parameters supplied to that function will also always be a part of that object.

Answer (score 3):

Does this fit the bill?

```
app.directive('arbitraryThing', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      params: '='
    }, 
    link: function(scope, element, attr)
      { 
        element.on(scope.params.action.directive, function(event){
          event.preventDefault();
          scope.params.action.value({ target: scope.params.params.target})
      })
    }
    }
  })
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/slr9M0YK0JuzcMPWrMqr?p=preview

Comment: Very nice solution, I think it's the right direction though I can't go by the assumption that the `fruit.action.directive` will be an event. It should be able to be an arbitrary directive such as `my-own-click-directive`.